# Angular 2 : Search pipe not working when input inside a form tag

Tags: angular, forms, input, angular-forms

```
<form autocomplete="off">
            <input  [(ngModel)]="query"  type="search"  class="form-control search-control"  placeholder="Search for orders (by order number)">
            </form>
......................

......................

......................


       <li  *ngFor="let cancelledOrders of cancel_order_array |  search:'id,order_no':query let i = index">
<div class="row">

......................
```

the search is not working when i place the input inside a **form** tag(otherwise it working properly),the reason i use it inside a form is the issue with the autofiil

is there any solution for the this?

Comment: @Asahiq did that fix your problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### For input tags inside a form either the `formControlName` should be assigned to it or should be defined as `standalone`.

so in your case
Add this to the input tag `[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"`

```
<input  [(ngModel)]="query" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"  type="search"  class="form-control search-control"  placeholder="Search for orders (by order number)">
```

Comment: @AashiqRathnadas Well ! :-)